# Как вызвать метод одного фрагмента из другого фрагмента android?

Tags: android

Я работаю с приложением в котором есть два списка сообщений, эти списки размещены в фрагментах, данные для заполнения списков берутся с сервера, что-бы сервер выдал нам эти данные нужен access_token, который со временем протухает и нужно посылать запрос на новый, в ответе приходит новый токен который я сохраняю в SharedPreferences. Так вот собственно и сам вопрос - как после получения нового токена, вызвать нужный мне фрагмент и его пересоздать. Вот метод который я использую для обновления токенов:

```
mAPIService2.getNewToken(new ReqAccessToken(token)).enqueue(new Callback<ResNewTokens>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResNewTokens> call, @NonNull Response<ResNewTokens> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    String n_access_token = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getAccess_token();
                    String n_refresh_token = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getRefresh_token();

                    new_acc_tok = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("access_token", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = new_acc_tok.edit();
                    editor.putString(ACCESS_TOKEN, n_access_token);
                    editor.apply();

                    new_ref_tok = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("refresh_token", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = new_ref_tok.edit();
                    editor1.putString(REFRESH_TOKEN, n_refresh_token);
                    editor1.apply();

                    received();

                } else {
                    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                    try {
                        if (Objects.requireNonNull(errorBody).string().contains("refresh_token_expired")) {
                            logOut();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResNewTokens> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
```

как видно из кода, я после получения токенов вызываю метод который тянет с сервера список сообщений с учетом нового access_token, а когда я открываю вкладку с отправленными сообщениями у меня пустой список, и выводится в логах сообщение, что access_token протух и нужно обновить, короче в итоге меня выкидывает на экран логина, после сообщения что рефреш уже не рабочий. Я не смогу найти нормального способа который пересоздает фрагмент, вернее мне нужно не весь фрагмент может пересоздавать а только вызывать функцию которая есть в другом фрагменте. Ведь если вызвать фрагмент то разве что только для замещения текущего. Короче не очень понятная ситуация получается если честно. Если кто знает как исправить сложившуюся ситуацию, то буду рад помощи.

Comment: копай в сторону RxJava. Избавляет от многих проблем, в том числе и эту.

Comment: вы я так понял имеете в виду использование RxJava для обновления токенов, или для вызова методов одного фрагмента из другого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я немного переделал логику своей проблемы, и теперь у меня каждый фрагмент запускается только тогда, когда выбрана вкладка с данным фрагментом. Это решение помогло мне избавится от парных запросов, которые идут одновременно с двух вкладок. Все функции фрагмента теперь запускаются при условии что вкладка, и соответственно фрагмент находится в фокусе. Если кто-то будет реализовывать подобное решение для себя то вот мой код который я использовал для себя:

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        isStarted = true;
        if (isVisible){
           мой запрос апи
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        isStarted = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        isVisible = isVisibleToUser;
        if (isVisible && isStarted){
            мой запрос апи
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать методы обратного вызова или по другому коллбеки. Фрагменты по официальным рекомендациям гугла должны коммуницировать только так, через активити и не имеют прямого сообщения между собой.

- FragmentA отправляет колбек с данными в Activity
- Activity получает данные и передает их в FragmentB. Или делает что-то
  другое, например, записывает данные в БД

В вашем примере это будет выглядеть вот так. FragmentA, который отправляет коллбек.

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
OnTokenReceivedListener mCallback;

public interface OnTokenReceivedListener {
    public void received(String token);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    //Проверка на то, что activity имплементирует колдбэк
    try {
        mCallback = (OnTokenReceivedListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnTokenReceivedListener");
    }
}
   .....

        @Override
        public void onResponse{ // это ваш onResponse, который в вопросе.
        //received()
        mCallback.received(n_refresh_token)
        }
```

Активити, которая получает коллбек и как-то реагирует на него.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements FragmentA.OnTokenReceivedListener{
...

public void received(String token) {
     FragmentB newFragment = new FragmentB();
        //Создаем Bundle, который прочитаем в нашем фрагменте FragmentB в onCreate
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("My Token", token);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        //Обычное создание фрагмента
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
}
}
```

Фрагмент который принимает данные

```
public class FragmentB{
String token;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments(); 
    if (bundle != null) { 
    token = bundle.getString("My Token", "");//ваш токен в фрагменте FragmentB  
    }
    }
 }
```

Comment: то есть нужно создавать полноценную активити, или можно просто класс создать который будет extend Activity?

Comment: У вашего фрагмента должен быть родитель. То есть активити, в которой вы создали FragmentA. Вот она и будет принимать коллбек от этого фрагмента. Если у вас архитектура одна активити - много фрагментов, то скоро вы поймете, что это архитектура не очень как раз из-за огромного количества таких вот коллбеков

Comment: а скажите пожалуйста @Valgaal, ваше решение направлено на отправку нового токена на нужный мне фрагмент, или просто пересоздание фрагмента?

Comment: В данном примере, как вы видите пересоздается фрагмент. Но если у вас этот фрагмент на экране, то тогда вы можете использовать его методы с этими данными. То есть если у вас на экране два фрагмента, то у вашей активити должны быть ссылки на эти фрашменты, потому что она их создавала. Вот и через эти ссылки можно передать данные. Если у вас на экране один фрагмент и вы хотите заменить его другим, то надо пересоздавать фрагмент, как написано в моем примере

Comment: `(OnTokenSelectedListener) SecondScreen.class;` этот кусок кода не принимается, вроде сделал все как у вас написано но `OnTokenSelectedListener` все-равно выделено красным, может что-то не дописал.

Comment: Там должна быть activity. Метод onAttach менять не надо

Comment: а `onAttach` может быть deprecated? вроде все как в вашем ответе сделал, но все равно слушатель выделен красным и теперь `onAttach`  - `deprecated`)

Comment: Ой, точно он Deprecated, потому что activity, а надо context, я изменю пост

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81757/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-valgaal).